# SQL get row by int | string

Tags: mysql, sql, hash

Im little bit stucked with my SQL query.

I've got a table with rows that can be identified by id or hash string...

| id | short | title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | asdadasdsd | foo |
| 2 | 1qweqweqwe | bar |
| 3 | yxcyxcyxcy | baz |

So SQL is quite easy...

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=<identifier> OR hash=<identifier>
```

What I found out is that when my identifier is hash and begins with number which could be found in the id column, MYSQL returning me "wrong" row.
For example when my identifier is "1qweqweqwe" result is row 1.
I think the reason for that is it converts my hash string into integer maybe? Is there a way how to disable this behaviour?
Or the only way is to regenerate all hashes into new formats without numbers in it?

Thank you for any clarification :)

Petr

Comment: This is an ooooold issue with how MySql violates the ansi standard. Any other DB, this query would fail to even run because of the conversion issue between a string and an varchar. It's not that `1qweqweqwe` would no longer match id 1. To be fully ansi-standard compliant you also wouldn't see id 2, because the query would just fail. You'd need something like Sql Server's `Try_Convert()` to get more-correct handling. This is also an extension to the standard, but it's a better match for how pretty much every other database does it.

Comment: Thank you Joel :)

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not have to regenerate the hashes. If both the id and hash match and you prefer
to pull row based on hash, then you could have the hash as the first match column condition. Basically it goes with the first match condition that is found to be true.

Also, I suppose you are already adding quotes to the hash string in the query. If not please do, as it will validate as a string then.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE hash='<identifier>' OR id=<identifier>
```

Comment: Actually Im using framework for build queries and It passes all values as strings. I will have to do some pre-logic. Thank you :)

Comment: @PetrLukáš Frameworks that do that tend to also handle sql injection incorrectly. That can be crazy-dangerous. It's a very fast way to get your db hacked.

Comment: Dont worry, framework itself has really good SQL injection protection build in ;)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be passing the identifier in as a string -- because it is.  But then you are comparing to a number (the `id`) and the string parameter is converted to a number.  MySQL does so by converting the leading digits, if any.

I don't like the logic of passing in a string for an identifier, so I would really suggest that you fix the calling logic and call *either*:

```
WHERE id = <int identifier>
```

or:

```
WHERE hash = <string identifier>
```

But if you want to keep your current version, you can convert to a string:

```
WHERE CAST(id AS CHAR) = <identifier> OR hash = <identifier>
```

Comment: Note that casting the id will prevent any index use for the id column. It's forcing a table scan.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn . . . I think the `OR` would already do that.

Comment: Possibly. I'm not as up on MySql, but it should be possible to get two index seeks instead of a table scan.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: Yes MySQL will use the two different indexes, and do a merge on the result from the result of these two indexes.

Comment: I think that my logic is OK. Iam calling method with array of ids which use library for build query. Ive got something like $selection->whereOr( [ short" => $ids, "id" => $ids ] );  and builded query is: "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ( ( `id` IN ('94-qweqwe')) OR (`short` IN ('94-qweqwe') ) )

Comment: I just wanted to know, if there is a way how to prevent database to ruin my "ids" thats all :)

Comment: "CAST(id AS CHAR) helped" ... thank you ;)